# Disable screen resize on windows with touchscreen

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, multi-touch

I'm developing a presentation-like local site (will be local, displayed on several screens and that's all) and i pick to develop on chrome (you know, awesome support for all neat stuff). Chrome will run as full screen window, on top of windows 7 (or maybe 8, who knows?)

The app/site will be operable trough a multi touch screen.

**However!**

Since the screen is multitouch, on pinch everything is zoomed in/out. There is a way of disabling this? (even with a separate app that will work on background, dunno). Also, i would like to be able to use multitouch in the app later on, but on custom stuff, not on screen resize...

Btw, i tried the trick i used on an iphone app:

```
document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e){ e.preventDefault(); }, false);
```

and:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```

But it seems it doesn't work.

Sooo... Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Which version of Chrome?  AFAIK `<meta name="viewport">` only landed in Chrome 19, and it's disabled until Chrome 20.

Comment: Latest version of chrome, auto updating.

Comment: Right now, the Chrome stable channel is 17, beta is 18, and unstable is 19.  I'm not sure if canary is 20 or not, but you can build from source.  If you're not building your own, go to About to see which channel you're on.

Comment: 18.x. Hmm... I'll try to use canary. Thanks

Comment: Ok, installed canary. There is something i have to do in order to enable this? Doesn't seems to work.

Comment: hmmm... i'm starting to think there is a new layer, which is on top of the browser. Because resize is made by resizing .... i don't know what is resized, because is not like classic zooming (ctrl+scroll).

The worse thing would be if this is driver related...

Comment: http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/ says there's an `--enable-viewport` switch but I don't see it in the latest source code.

Comment: Ok, even if is a late reply, this did worked :) However, for some reason, initial-scale=1 doesn't zoom to desired width (even if i specify width=1920), but it does a zoom out, down to 0.5 or so. It's a good starting point tho :)

Please add it as an answer to be able to accept it ;)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Best solution for now (until google updates chrome, if they ever will) is to disable gestures in your touchscreen/mouse/touchpad settings. Control panel -> Mouse -> Device Settings -> (pick device) -> Settings -> Disable pinch zoom.

Answer (score 1):

I am working on a similar project (browser-based digital kiosk with multitouch screen) and ran in to the same problem.

Since I have not found a work around in Chrome I am switching to Firefox. You can disable pinch zooming in Firefox by navigating to 'about:config' and changing the values for browser.gesture.pinch.in and browser.gesture.pinch.out to "".